# In the AWS Javascript SDK, is there a way to test credentials?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm writing a web app to layer some tools on top of our AWS account. I want to limit access to this web app to only those who have the appropriate access. I'm not really sure what to check (maybe which group they're in?) and how to check it (short of submitting `dry-run` calls to "test" their credentials?)

The flow would be something like..

- User navigates to this page
- Specifies what they want to do (via some prewritten scripts)
- The page prompts them for a user/password associated with their AWS account
- Execute the script (which will have access to do everything from start/stop EC2 to creating new ECS task definitions, modifying Route53, etc.)

What's the best way to validate that the user hitting my web app actually has permissions to execute these calls? Is there a SDK option to pass in credentials with calls, or create a credential object of some sort and test that?

A specific example of the SDK that I want to use is http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html#registerTaskDefinition-property

Comment: Why do you need that? Can't you just display an error when the call to the service is made?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito lets you specify separate roles for anonymous and authenticated users, with the policies you define for accessing other services: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

In this broadcast we went through implementing a javascript example: https://www.twitch.tv/videos/132010411

Comment: I appreciate that, but watching a 2.5 hour video isn't really a great option for me :)

Comment: @Julio_AWS_DevRel I think OP is thinking of AWS users -- rather than application users (including Cognito users) -- operating under the impression that there's a concept of an external site accessing the resources in user's AWS account via delegation of permissions from the "logged in" user.  If he isn't willing to watch a 2.5 hour video, I'n not sure he's going to like the implications of my answer. :)

Comment: There are many ways to cut this, but overall i think cognito is probably simpler an less error prone than DIY on STS.

Comment: I think you are making an assumption about the use case.  Read it again with the following in mind, and see if you can see what I see, in the question. I could be wrong.  What's being discussed -- as I read it -- is this. 
 He wants you to log in to his app, using *your own* AWS credentials... and then his app will manipulate *your* AWS resources, in *your* AWS account -- not his. How would that work? Otherwise, of course, I'd say "Cognito" as well.

Comment: I'm definitely willing to watch a 2.5 hour video, just not until I'm sure it's what we need :) --- and yes the usecase is more simply put that, we share aws accounts, non-prod and prod, and I simply want to limit the automation scripts to those who under normal circumstances could sign in to AWS directly and manually run everything already, using their existing accounts. I just want to validate that they do in fact have _authorization_ to do what this web-tool will automate.

Comment: It appears that I have read something into the question that wasn't there.